# Basic biographical data of contemporary mathematicians

Tags: ho.history-overview

I'm writing for a broad audience about a collection of topics of math, and including the dates of birth and death of all people mentioned, just to help the reader to keep a general idea of when different things happened. I still could not manage to find the dates for Meigu Guan (who contributed with the formulation of the chinese postman problem),
for H. Peyton Young and Michel Balinski (who contributed in the area of social choice), and Chris Skinner, at Princeton. Can anyone provide the missing dates? Hopefully, they themselves could do it. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find out DOB and DOD for Meigu Guan myself while preparing a biographical addendum for a book, but haven't succeeded - I hope someone will help both you and me. H. Peyton Young was born in 1945 (source: Library of Congress cataloging-in Publication Data).Michel Balinski was born in 1933 (source: A mathematical view of our world by Harold R. Parks, Roger Maurer, Lynn Trimpe), Skinner was born in 1972 (source: his CV).

Comment: In the meantime I have contacted H. Peyton Young and Michel Balinski, and I can confirm your dates are accurate (the also provided the birthday). I've got no news about Guan. Skinner is a different person. I'll continue looking for the mising data and let you know If I succeed to fill it. Thanks for your attention. Best regards. Omar